# Fetch articles of Facebook Media Blog by keywords

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Media Blog, https://www.facebook.com/facebookmedia/blog does not have a sign in option. Users can directly access articles. I need to retrieve articles based on keyword from that blog. I don't see documentation for apis of facebook media blog. Can someone give an insight on that?

For example wikipedia has an opensearch api for searching pages through keywords.

This endpoint of wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=rainbow gives output in json format related to rainbow. I expect a similar output.

Comment: I don’t think there is any API for that, that is somewhat outside of “normal” Facebook.

Comment: So for retrieving that what approach should I follow?